# Can i get video feed from web player into android application?

Tags: android, networking, image-processing, wowza

i want to be able to get video feed from a web player like JW Player .. The thing i want to achieve is an app for android that sends live camera feed to a web server then the web server should broadcast it to another android app which is the master app .. the master app can then draw something on the screen which i want it to be drawn on the video and then sending the edited video back to the server and then back to the android which was broadcasting in the first place.

i want to achieve something like this : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0CyKER2Wdco

i've searched and found a tutorial that uses Wowza but it's half the answer .. i still want to edit it and then back to the server and then to the android .. here's a link to it : http://www.androidhive.info/2014/06/android-streaming-live-camera-video-to-web-page/

any help will be much appreciated.

edit : i want to know if it is possible to broadcast video from android phone to webserver then apply some edit then send it back to the phone

Comment: This question feels too broad. Stack Overflow suggests that "Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much." See: [http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: i just wanted the tools to get me started ..